# JSLint Expected 'set' and instead saw ''

Tags: javascript, jslint

[JS Linting](http://www.jslint.com) the following bit of code:

```
/*jslint 
browser: true,
es5: true,
*/

var VCA = {
    get enable () {
        'use strict';
        return 0;
    },
    set enable (value) {
        'use strict';
        console.log(value);
    }
};
```

Results in the error:

```
Problem at line 11 character 9: Expected 'set' and instead saw ''.

set enable (value) {
```

I don't understand what to do to make this see `'set'` correctly?!

I know about the `__defineGetter__` syntax but really want to use the above style.

Does anyone have more information on this error?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for Douglas's email inbox.

Comment: @Tomalak - I didn't know if my systax was wrong.  Will file it as a bug report.

Comment: whether?  You mean instead of if?

Comment: Yes, that's right :) Pet hate!

Comment: Ha, ok.  Could I niggle you for an explanation? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3254/discussion-between-matt-clarkson-and-tomalak-geretkal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a problem in JSLint. I can't get any get/set scenario to validate in JSLint. Your syntax seems to be right, and in line with Douglas' [initial post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120313195934/http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/1258) about getter setter validation.

---

**edit**: this validates fine, so might be a workaround :-)

```
var myObject = {};

(function () {
    var myProp = 'myDefault';
    Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'myProp', 
        {
            enumerable:     false,
            configurable:   true,
            get: function () {
                return myProp;
            },
            set: function (value) {
                myProp = value + ' lala';
            }
        });
}());
```

Comment: Opera doesn't support Object.defineProperty and IE doesn't support Matt's example syntax, so you have to use both if you want compatibility.

Comment: Mweh, most of the folks that are using ES5 in strict mode are not using it in a web environment.

Comment: I only have "user strict" because JS Lint defaults to ES5.

Comment: You can just use the `sloppy: true` flag :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, some seven years plus later, I'll record that the below now lints, if only to provide an example for using getters & setters in JSLint in 2018.

```
/*jslint getset, devel */

var VCA = {
    get enable() {
        "use strict";
        return 0;
    },
    set enable(value) {
        "use strict";
        console.log(value);
    }
};
```